# How to merge both public and user Firebase Database rules?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Is there any way to combine or use both the rules that is Public and User in Firebase Database->Rules section.
In simple words can I include both rules?
Thanks in advance!
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to remove the images and replace them with the actual text.  You can simply copy and paste, then format as code.  Text is easier to search and read.

Answer (score 2):

Combining your rules would make no sense, since:

> Shallower security rules override rules at deeper paths. Child rules can only grant additional privileges to what parent nodes have already declared. They cannot revoke a read or write privilege.

[source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#read_and_write_rules_cascade)

So once you grant read/write permission on the root of your database, you can't revoke that permission at a lower level.